# aiobotocore dynamodb no attribute 'has_event_stream_output'

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, python-asyncio

trying to do some work on dynamodb using asyncio,
all my actions return an Error:

```
AttributeError: 'OperationModel' object has no attribute 'has_event_stream_output'
```

this is at the level of aiobotocore/endpoint.py
sample code (can even make it simpler with just a call to list_tables):

```
import asyncio
import aiobotocore


async def main(loop):
    session = aiobotocore.get_session(loop=loop)
    table_name = 'testTable'
    async with session.create_client('dynamodb') as client:
        response = await client.describe_table(TableName=table_name)
        print(response)

asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

aiobotocore 0.9.2
python 3.5